# Sql Server batch insert takes 10s, problem?

Tags: sql-server, subsonic, batch-file

I have a large batch insert using SubSonic which takes about 10s (sometimes more), will this produce any problems if my website tries to open another connection to my sql server?

This batch won't happend that often, but I guess it will happend at the same time as an other connection at some point.

And a related question: How many connections can sql server have at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server can handle simultaneous batches just fine.  Of course, it's possible that your `insert` batch locks certain table rows.  That will block other transactions from completing until the batch is finished.

The usual limit on SQL Server connections is the `max pool size` of the connection pool on the client.